# DriveFile.trash(GoogleApiClient) method is gone

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services, google-drive-android-api

Android sample code has trash() method (see [same code github](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/TrashFileActivity.java))

```
DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(getGoogleApiClient(), result.getDriveId());
file.trash(getGoogleApiClient()).setResultCallback(trashCallback);
```

I use the latest google play service library (updated on March 17).

But DriveFile class does not contain trash() method.

How to trash file?

Must use Google-Drive-SDK for java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it was an OOPS. The code on Github disappeared with a commit msg "remove trashing activity". But at least it looks like it's coming soon. Meanwhile, I stick with this [SO 22295903](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295903/how-to-delete-a-file-on-google-drive-using-google-drive-android-api) solution. Messy, but at least something.