# New Google Drive API, trashing files, folders and storing application data in app folder

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am really glad that there was an update in the new Google Drive Android API recently, which finally added support for app folders and change listeners. 
As I was testing this new API, I wanted to delete all files and folders in this app folder at one point. 
I have found that the simplest way to do this will be to remove the app from Google Drive.
Unfortunately, when I opened app manager in Google Drive, i didn't find my app there. 
I have found Google Documents, Forms, Drawings, Presentations and two Google Tables - probably the old and the new ones. 
There are also two additional suspicious looking apps, one called simply Google Drive, the other one Project Default Service Account - both without an icon.

So my first question is "How can I put(add,show) my app there and then see it's content ?"

I have also recently found that there is no method to trash files or folders with this new Google Drive Android API, but it seems that it was there before and then was removed.

My second question is "Is there any option to trash files right now(probably not) with the new API only ?"

My third, last question is "How long will it take until a new update which will hopefully feature this option is released ?"

Comment: Please start a new question for each question that you have. Also, #3 is off-topic. We're not Google support.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I understand that most of the people here won't know the answer for the 3rd question, but I also know that here are some people from Google Drive team who could give me at least approximate time, how long will it take. If 3 weeks or 3 months for example.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Quoting your: "We're not Google support", I beg to differ. This place is the only support Google Drive Team is giving us at the moment. Please see: https://developers.google.com/drive/support/

Comment: We watch this to answer questions on correct usage of the APIs, particularly new APIs which should all fall under general StackOverflow best practices. If you have feature requests you can ask about them on the G+ page.  We don't comment on timelines for future features (whenever you make a public statement about timelines, you guarantee that something will happen to disrupt it).

Comment: @CherylSimon Above all, I highly value your work here, the promptness of your responses as well as your knowledge. BTW, do you understand the question #1 (about the app folder)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the "Project Default Service Account" is your app.  Did you double check the app name and icon in the cloud console?  I believe that is a default app name that is used if you don't set anything.

Comment: Thank you, it was really my app. It's a pity that i am not able to see the folders content(it would be great at least when developing), but thank you anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the question #1 so I'll let others to elaborate.

Question #2: NO. Please see [SO 22703040](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22703040/drivefile-trashgoogleapiclient-method-is-gone/22725728#22725728)

Question #3: You will never know unless you are the Google developer yourself. Maybe not even then.