# How to create file in DriveAPI overriding if it exists?

Tags: android, android-file, google-drive-android-api

I realized that when calling "createFile", it creates a new file even if its title is an already existing title.

What am doing now is to search for the file first and if i can't find it, i create it. Two methods for a simple problem.

There is a better way to create a file overriding it if already it exists?

Answer (score 4):

Google Drive is actually a 'flat' model, where every object is identified by it's unique ID.

So, when an object (file/folder) is created, it gets a unique ID. The object may/not have content. Everything else is 'metadata'. The tree structure of popular OSs is actually 'faked' by metadata links (parent links). That means in Google Drive you may have **multiple children** with the same metadata (title/name) in a parent object. And you may also have **multiple parents** for any child object (single object appears in multiple parents' folders).

All this rant means one thing for your situation:

Once you create a file/folder and get hold of it's ID, '*creation of a new file with the same name*' can be accomplished by modifying it's content and/or metadata (you can see a [typical example here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/andyscan/gdrtdemo/GDAA.java#L225)).

If you take the path of delete/create (which is also possible, [but had not been until recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295903/how-to-delete-a-file-on-google-drive-using-google-drive-android-api/22368859#22368859)), you are actually:
1/ modifying the original file/folder's 'trashed/deleted' metadata
2/ creating a brand new object with a different ID

Think twice before you select the method you use. UPDATE method is a 'one-step', approach preferable in async environment (create MUST wait for successful delete).  On the other hand, if you use DELETE/CREATE approach you may be able to take advantage of the fact that 'trashed' object will be around for a while.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I think files are uniquely identified by their ID in the Drive API. Therefore you have no way to control for the title using the drive API itself. So doing it yourself is probably the way to go.

EDIT: The ID is what is important with all that synchronisation happening. A title could change easily therefore using it as a unique identifier would be a bad idea. Hence the unique ID.

What you could do if the file already exists is either remove it and replace it by the new one (bad idea I would say) or simply add an extra number at the end of the new file that will be added to the folder.